# Background shorthand property assignment?

Tags: html, css

What does the 2 zeroes in

```
background: 0 0
```

mean. When using the shorthand property the order of the property values is:

```
background-color
background-image
background-repeat
background-attachment
background-position
```

Can `background-image` have 0 value?

Answer (score 2):

The CSS:
    `background: 0 0;`
would set the background image to position 0px 0px, provided the background image is defined after `background: 0 0`.
Eg:

```
background: 0 0;
background-image: url(image/bg.jpg);
```

Answer (score 0):

The CSS `background` shorthand property lets you adjust all of the available background style options at once, including `color`, `image`, `origin` and `size`, `repeat` method, and other features. background can be used to set the values for one or more of: `background-clip` `background-color` `background-image` `background-origin`  `background-position`  `background-repeat` `background-size` and     `background-attachment`

In shorthand `0 0` properties used for background image positioning example:

```
/* <length> values */
background-position: 0 0;
```

that means background-image is placed at the `top-left` corner of an element

*Moreover*  this properties

```
background-color: #000;
background-image: url(images/bg.gif);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: left top;
```

in shorthand will be like this...

`background: #000 url(images/bg.gif) no-repeat left top;`

Comment: In addition, this doesn't really answer the question, what exactly *does* the 0 0 variables do?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have `background: 0 0;` by default. What it means is to set the X&Y positions of your background image to start at 0,0 coordinates which also means the default position.

If using `background: 0 0;` alone without providing an actual background image would not provide any different at all.

Here is an example of background image position set to

```
background: -10px 20px;
```

[image: background image position]